# In objective-c what is the alternative to using YES/NO when using #define and #if

Tags: objective-c, conditional-compilation

Because of the way in which YES/NO are defined, you cannot use YES/NO with `#if`, such as `#define CAN_DO  YES` which indicates the code controlled by tag CAN_DO should be 'turned on' usually using `#if CAN_DO`. As an old school C guy I would use `#define CAN_DO 1` but feel like it is not very 'Objective-C like'.  Is there a preferred'Objective-C' way to do this? (BTW I am aware of `#ifdef` but those who will use the tag would be best served by always providing the `#defined`'d symbol).

To put in more simply, I'd like the people who will set the symbols in their 'user' code to be able to say something like `#define SOME_SYMBOL YES`. But I'm getting the idea that the C way `#define SOME_SYMBOL 1` is as good as it gets.

Comment: Give a more concrete example, it's not clear what you're asking here.

Comment: Just use 1 and 0. The only difference is that `YES` and `NO` are typecast when they are defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The old-school C approach is exactly the correct approach.  For example, see how `NS_BLOCKS_AVAILABLE` is defined in `NSObjCRuntime.h`.

Comment: Agreed.  If you need to use preprocessor constructs, then you won't necessarily be able to use ObjC constructs with them.  Nothing wrong with that, they're different things.